# Maximum capacitance on 12 V ATX PSU

Tags: capacitor, circuit-design, design, atx

I'm designing a fan controller for a PC. It will be controlling 6 fans. I want to start initially with 100 µF tantalum capacitor for each fan. Can 600 µF capacitance on the 12 V line (4-pin, 5.08 mm Molex) cause any problems? Line 12 V will probably be protected by a varistor and a polyswitch.

Comment: What does the datasheet for the PSU say? And are you sure you need so much capacitance for your fan controllers? That feels like a lot for just driving a fan.

Comment: It looks a bit excessive, but I saw fan controllers that used 100µF blocking capacitors, so I think it should be good value to start with.

Comment: Blocking capacitors? Why would a fan controller use a blocking capacitor?

Comment: Sorry, I meant bypass capacitors.

Comment: 100uF capacitors won't be effective at bypassing. 100nF is a more typical value.

Comment: Tantalum caps are expensive and tend to catch fire when they fail, use aluminum electrolytic capacitors unless you have clear requirements that only tantalum can fulfill and you have designed around their limitations.

Answer (score 0):

According to ATX power supply specification, the 12V line has a maximum capacitive load of 1000 uF.

Therefore, putting a 100 uF for each fan and having 600 uF just for a fan controller sounds unreasonable.

It means only 400 uF is allowed for the rest of the system.

Also, specifically, using 100uF tantalum capacitors also sounds unreasonable. Having tantalum caps without no good reason just for a simple fan controller does not make much sense.

If your fan controller needs 100 uF tantalum per fan, I suggest looking for another fan controller.